# How to determine which file corresponds to a screen on an Android app?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, logcat

I'm working on a very large android app which is broken into many different modules. When I'm given a task it can be hard to find which file I need to be working on.

My hope was to connect a device to Android Studio, navigate to the relevant screen on the app, and use Logcat to filter out ActivityManager to find out the activity name. This worked fine in the past but hasn't worked so well for this large codebase.

So I wanted to ask if anyone has any advice on how to solve this issue? Right now I end up wasting an inordinate amount of time simply trying to find which file match up to the current screen and it's stressing me out.

Edit: I should also say, is there a standard way to approach this? Should there be some sort of documentation available? In general what's the best approach to matching up files with screens? Thank you.

Comment: One way would be to connect a device to Android Studio, navigate to the relevant screen on the app and use the "Layout Inspector" to find some relevant information about the screen such as ids that are in used. With the id, you can do a global search to locate the XML file (assuming that is what you are using) and with the name of the XML file you should be able to identify the activity/fragment. I haven't actually done this, but it seems that it will work.

Comment: @Cheticamp That's a good idea, thank you for sharing! I'll try that out and see how it works in practice for sure.

Comment: So, my suggestion didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this capability. It seems that in Layout Inspector for APIs 29, 30 and, presumably, above that the declared attribute section can [identify the layout source](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector#4-0-0-live-layout-inspector).

[image]

Just run the app in an API 29+ emulator or device.